# Duplicate element of tensor while perserving gradient values

Tags: python, pytorch

So I have a vector that I computed somehow with size `k`

```
x = torch.FloatTensor([0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0.7])
x = x + 2
```

I want to take its first element `x[0]` and create a vector of size `k-1` filled with the value x[0] so that the gradients that come along with this element are present in the new vector.

I tried using `torch.full` and filling it up with `x[0]` but that does not preserve gradients.

Using pytorch 1.4

Comment: Please read the description for the [tag:ml] tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use `.repeat` like this (IMO cleaner and more verbose):

```
# type deduction is automatic
x = torch.tensor([0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0.7])
x = x + 2
y = x[0].repeat(50)
```

Gradient will be preserved (gradient history will be copied).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use indexing for that:

```py
y = x[[0] * (k - 1)]  # take x[0] k-1 times
```

Comment: You sure this will preserve the gradients?

Comment: @RanElgiser this should. but you better check